# Error with a Entity Framework Connection and App Pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, web-config

Hello, I have the code which returns an array of object to me and it works fine on my test environment. However, on my Production environment when calling the function, after sometime I get the below error until I refresh my App Pool and it continues working fine.

> 2017-10-09 19:09:54,766 [111] ERROR .ctor -
>   System.NullReferenceException: **Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object**.    at
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExtractAccessorValuesIntoParam(OracleParameterCollection
>   paramColl, OracleConnection connection, Int32 paramCount, String
>   commandText, Int64 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, Int64
>   internalInitialLOBFS, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean
>   bCallFromExecuteReader)    at
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass57.b__56()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass57.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__55()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior
>   transactionalBehavior, String commandText, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior
>   transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior
>   transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   MasterSuiteV1.services.AccountVeririficationService.GetNamesUsingExadata(VerificationDto
>   dto)

Below is the code of the function;

```
using (var repo = new ExaDataConContext())
                        {
                            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                            {
                                Logger.Info("About to call eonepkg.extract_cus_dtls");

                                var dat =
                                repo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("begin eonepkg.extract_cus_dtls (:bra,:cus,:cur,:led,:sub,:mapaccno,:adname,:results); end;",
                                    new object[] { new OracleParameter("bra", OracleDbType.Int16,DBNull.Value,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("cus", OracleDbType.Int32,DBNull.Value,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("cur", OracleDbType.Int32,DBNull.Value,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("led", OracleDbType.Int32,DBNull.Value,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("sub", OracleDbType.Int32,DBNull.Value,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("mapaccno", OracleDbType.Varchar2,dto.NubanAcc,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("adname", OracleDbType.Varchar2,user.UserId,ParameterDirection.Input),
                                           new OracleParameter("results",OracleDbType.Int32,ParameterDirection.Output)});

                                Logger.Info("Succesfully called eonepkg.extract_cus_dtls");

                                Logger.Info("About to select from GTB_CUS_DTLS Table");

                                var a = repo.ExecuteQuery<GetCustomerDetailsResponseDto>("select * from GTB_CUS_DTLS", new object[] { }).ToList();
                                scope.Complete();
                                Logger.Info("Succesfully selected from GTB_CUS_DTLS Table");
                                return a;
                            }
                        }
```

While below is the key in my Config File;

```
<add name="accVerifier" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=)));User ID ="";Password="";Persist Security Info=True;Max Pool Size=150;Connection Timeout=60;" />
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the layout of your question. Reducing hor. scrolling is greatly appreciated!